# WebDriver with Java - Not able to get all the text using Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm not able to get all the text on this website - https://niftygateway.com/marketplace

Using this simple code -

```
String iterativeXpath = "(//*[@id='root']/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div)";
        iterativeXpath = iterativeXpath.substring(0, iterativeXpath.length()-1);
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
        for(int i = 1; i <=20; i++){
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(iterativeXpath+"["+i+"])")));
           System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath(iterativeXpath+"["+i+"])")).getText());
        }
```

Comment: can you post error logs or output which you received ?

Comment: Use this css selector : p.MuiTypography-root.jss416.MuiTypography-body1

Comment: Are you going to get all text, in the site every element have different web elements and tags and div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all the text on this website https://niftygateway.com/marketplace you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://niftygateway.com/marketplace");
  System.out.println(driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.MuiCardContent-root")).stream().map(element->element.getText()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
  ```

---

Ideally, you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://niftygateway.com/marketplace");
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'MuiCardContent-root')]"))).stream().map(element->element.getText()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
  ```

Console Output:

```
[ATLAS #2/21
Symbiocene Mythologica
$1,333.00, The Flipper #86/99
The Title by Pak
Make Offer, A Trebled Man #7/20
Select Works by Alotta Money
$1,850.00, UNISWAP #164/261
Banned From The Internet Open Edition by Slime Sunday
$725.00, Peng - Shiny #5/5
Crystal Pops - Winter Edition by Goldweard
$1,500.00, Gucci Ghost Aqua Pink #17/20
Nifty Ghost Collection by Trevor Andrew
$2,500.00, Entangled #7/15
Tranquility by Andreas Wannerstedt
$333.33, The Day I Decided to Fly #72/268
Growing Up...I'm Scared Open Edition by FEWOCiOUS
$413.00, Extrusion #447/457
The Collision by Pak x Trevor Jones
Make Offer, A Trebled Man #13/20
Select Works by Alotta Money
$1,888.88, The Square #5/6
The Japanese Garden by Six n Five
$2,500.00, The Last Stand of the Nation State
Open Edition by Slimesunday
$1,325.00, Kikai Ningyou #16/20
Twisted Vacancy Edition
Not Accepting Offers, Extrusion #63/457
The Collision by Pak x Trevor Jones
Not Accepting Offers, The Sprite
Metamorphosis Open Edition By Metageist
$178.88, Inu - Shiny #15/15
Crystal Pops Asia Edition
$358.88, Pandy - Shiny #14/40
Crystal Pops Asia Edition
$228.88, Peng #24/30
Crystal Pops - Winter Edition by Goldweard
$288.88, Tiggz - Shiny #39/75
Crystal Pops Asia Edition
$125.88, A Trebled Man #20/20
Select Works by Alotta Money
$2,500.00]
```

Answer (score 0):

To wait for the list can use `visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy`.

And the `div.MuiCardContent-root.jss414` selector looks better:

```
driver.get("https://niftygateway.com/marketplace");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
List<WebElement> elements = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("div.MuiCardContent-root.jss414")));

for(WebElement element: elements) {
    System.out.println(element.getText());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your XPath. Here is the XPath for the product name text. This will give you all the elements that have the product name. Then only you can use the 'getText()' method.

```
//div[@class='MuiPaper-root MuiCard-root sc-Axmtr hvJMgY jss413 MuiPaper-elevation0 MuiPaper-rounded']/div/p[1]
```

Use this technique to get all the texts that you want.