# Selenium Streams - NoSuchElementException

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, java-stream, webdriverwait, nosuchelementexception

Can someone please help me out with this code. I'm getting NoSuchElement exception when I'm using streams. The `foreach()` alternative(Commented) is working fine. I want to know why it is throwing the exception if implemented with streams. Here is the code for your reference:

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\Sajidh\\WebDriver\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("https://rahulshettyacademy.com/seleniumPractise/#/");
WebElement product = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.product")).stream().filter(p->p.findElement(By.cssSelector("h4.product-name")).getText().contains("Potato")).collect(Collectors.toList()).get(0);
// WebElement product = null;
// for(WebElement p : driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.product")))
// {
// if(p.findElement(By.cssSelector("h4.product-name")).getText().contains("Potato"))
// {
// product = p;
// break;
// }
// }
System.out.println(product.findElement(By.cssSelector("h4.product-name")).getText());
System.out.println(product.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.quantity")).getText());
System.out.println(product.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.product-action button:nth-child(1)")).size());
product.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.product-action button:nth-child(1)")).click();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To print the `textContent` of all the elements you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the [`visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65677878/webdriver-with-java-not-able-to-get-all-the-text-using-webdriver/65686528#65686528) and you can use *Java8* [`stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) and [`map()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  import java.util.stream.Collectors;

  import org.openqa.selenium.By;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\WebDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
  ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
  options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
  driver.get("https://rahulshettyacademy.com/seleniumPractise/#/");
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("div.product h4.product-name"))).stream().map(element->element.getText()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//div[@class='product']//h4[@class='product-name']"))).stream().map(element->element.getText()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
  driver.quit();
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  [Brocolli - 1 Kg, Cauliflower - 1 Kg, Cucumber - 1 Kg, Beetroot - 1 Kg, Carrot - 1 Kg, Tomato - 1 Kg, Beans - 1 Kg, Brinjal - 1 Kg, Capsicum, Mushroom - 1 Kg, Potato - 1 Kg, Pumpkin - 1 Kg, Corn - 1 Kg, Onion - 1 Kg, Apple - 1 Kg, Banana - 1 Kg, Grapes - 1 Kg, Mango - 1 Kg, Musk Melon - 1 Kg, Orange - 1 Kg, Pears - 1 Kg, Pomegranate - 1 Kg, Raspberry - 1/4 Kg, Strawberry - 1/4 Kg, Water Melon - 1 Kg, Almonds - 1/4 Kg, Pista - 1/4 Kg, Nuts Mixture - 1 Kg, Cashews - 1 Kg, Walnuts - 1/4 Kg]
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  import java.util.stream.Collectors;

  import org.openqa.selenium.By;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\WebDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
  ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
  options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
  driver.get("https://rahulshettyacademy.com/seleniumPractise/#/");
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("div.product h4.product-name"))).stream().map(element->element.getText()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//div[@class='product']//h4[@class='product-name']"))).stream().map(element->element.getText()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
  driver.quit();
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  [Brocolli - 1 Kg, Cauliflower - 1 Kg, Cucumber - 1 Kg, Beetroot - 1 Kg, Carrot - 1 Kg, Tomato - 1 Kg, Beans - 1 Kg, Brinjal - 1 Kg, Capsicum, Mushroom - 1 Kg, Potato - 1 Kg, Pumpkin - 1 Kg, Corn - 1 Kg, Onion - 1 Kg, Apple - 1 Kg, Banana - 1 Kg, Grapes - 1 Kg, Mango - 1 Kg, Musk Melon - 1 Kg, Orange - 1 Kg, Pears - 1 Kg, Pomegranate - 1 Kg, Raspberry - 1/4 Kg, Strawberry - 1/4 Kg, Water Melon - 1 Kg, Almonds - 1/4 Kg, Pista - 1/4 Kg, Nuts Mixture - 1 Kg, Cashews - 1 Kg, Walnuts - 1/4 Kg]
  ```

Comment: Hi Debanjan, Thank you for  your help. The printing is working fine for me. I have problem with the streams statement on line no.5. It is returning NoSuchElementException. Do you have any idea why it is happening?