# How can I extract a list of id's from a webpage?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, java-stream

I have this code in a web page I am trying to scrape with selenium:

```
 <h4 class="category" id="sc_14295">...</h4>
 <h4 class="category" id="sc_14292">...</h4>
 <h4 class="category" id="sc_14291">...</h4>
 <h4 class="category" id="sc_14299">...</h4>
```

I have tried to implement a method like this (which I found here on SO) to get at least one id:

```
String id = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='category']")).getAttribute("id");
```

in this way:

```
String id = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h4[@class='category']")).getAttribute("id");
```

It doesn't work. I assume I should be using `findElements()` but that can't have getAtttribute. How can I extract a list of all id's?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### edit##

Does not saw the `java` tag, but procedure is the same.

---

This get one element and you can grab the id directly:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h4[@class = 'category']").get_attribute("id")
```

This get multiple elements, but you have to loop them to get the id of each:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//h4[@class = 'category']"):
```

**Example**

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Program Files\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')

html_content = """
<h4 class="category" id="sc_14295">...</h4>
 <h4 class="category" id="sc_14292">...</h4>
 <h4 class="category" id="sc_14291">...</h4>
 <h4 class="category" id="sc_14299">...</h4>
"""

driver.get("data:text/html;charset=utf-8,{html_content}".format(html_content=html_content))


for element in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//h4[@class = 'category']"):
        print(element.get_attribute("id"))

driver.close()
```

**Output**

```
sc_14295
sc_14292
sc_14291
sc_14299
```

Answer (score 0):

To print the *List* of *id* attribute of the elements you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the [`visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65677878/webdriver-with-java-not-able-to-get-all-the-text-using-webdriver/65686528#65686528) and you can use *Java8* [`stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) and [`map()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("h4.category"))).stream().map(element->element.getAttribute("id")).collect(Collectors.toList()));
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//h4[@class='category']"))).stream().map(element->element.getAttribute("id")).collect(Collectors.toList()));
  ```