# How find all items on the header section on WebSite?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I have this code:

```
<ul class="sidebar-menu left">
    <li index="1">Apple</li>
    <li index="2">Orange</li>
    <li index="3">Banana</li>
</ul>
```

How can I add this list(all li) to List<WebElement.>?

Answer (score 1):

To print all the header section texts you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the [`visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65677878/webdriver-with-java-not-able-to-get-all-the-text-using-webdriver/65686528#65686528) and you can use *Java8* [`stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) and [`map()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *cssSelector* and `getText()`:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("ul.sidebar-menu.left li"))).stream().map(element->element.getText()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
  ```
- Using *xpath* and `getAttribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//ul[@class='sidebar-menu left']//li"))).stream().map(element->element.getAttribute("innerHTML")).collect(Collectors.toList()));
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If this class is unique

```
sidebar-menu left
```

then you can construct this

1. cssSelector

   ```
   ul.sidebar-menu.left li
   ```
2. xpath

   ```
   //ul[contains(@class,'sidebar-menu left')]//child::li[@index]
   ```

child is just specification, you can remove that as well

```
//ul[contains(@class,'sidebar-menu left')]//li[@index]
```

They should represent multiple node in HTMLDOM, in this example it would be 3.

to add to list of web element, simply use `findElements` (plural)

```
List<WebElement> elems = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[contains(@class,'sidebar-menu left')]//child::li[@index]"));
```

In case you want to retrieve web element text,

```
for (WebElement e : elems){
       e.getText();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `findElements` by `xpath` with

```
xpath = "//ul[@class ='sidebar-menu left']//li"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `findElements` method.

```
    ArrayList<String> fruitNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<WebElement> fruits = driver
            .findElements(By.xpath("//ul[contains(@class,'sidebar-menu left')]//child::li[@index]"));

    for (WebElement element : fruits) {
        fruitNames.add(element.getText());
    }
```