# Selenium: How do I check if an element is on a page without use implicitlyWait?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How do I check if an element is on a page without use function implicitlyWait?
I may check that element is on page with use implicitlyWait:

```
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    if (driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(MY_CSS_SELECTOR)).size() != 0) {
        //...
    }
```

Is there any analogue of the solution?

Comment: You must use explicit wait (WebdriverWait)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already using `findElements`,  Note that `findElements` will not throw any error even the passed locators is not available in HTMLDOM.

If it finds, it will return a list of web elements.

Now `findElements` will try to `POLL` the `DOM` if it does not find anything `immediately`, so that's the reason we use ImplicitWait.

Since you've mentioned that you do not wanna deal with ImplicitWait, and wants to grab the list of web elements, you either have to use ExplicitWait

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("css_selector_here")));
```

or

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("css_selector_here")));
```

But note that using `explicit wait`, if elements are not found then You will likely get **TimeOutException**.

**ExplicitWait:**

Explicit waits are available to Selenium clients for imperative, procedural languages. They allow your code to halt program execution, or freeze the thread, until the condition you pass it resolves. The condition is called with a certain frequency until the timeout of the wait is elapsed. This means that for as long as the condition returns a falsy value, it will keep trying and waiting.

Since explicit waits allow you to wait for a condition to occur, they make a good fit for synchronizing the state between the browser and its DOM, and your WebDriver script.

**ImplicitWait:**

There is a second type of wait that is distinct from explicit wait called implicit wait. By implicitly waiting, WebDriver polls the DOM for a certain duration when trying to find any element. This can be useful when certain elements on the webpage are not available immediately and need some time to load.

Implicit waiting for elements to appear is disabled by default and will need to be manually enabled on a per-session basis. Mixing explicit waits and implicit waits will cause unintended consequences, namely waits sleeping for the maximum time even if the element is available or condition is true.

Warning: Do not mix implicit and explicit waits. Doing so can cause unpredictable wait times. For example, setting an implicit wait of 10 seconds and an explicit wait of 15 seconds could cause a timeout to occur after 20 seconds.

An implicit wait is to tell WebDriver to poll the DOM for a certain amount of time when trying to find an element or elements if they are not immediately available. The default setting is 0, meaning disabled. Once set, the implicit wait is set for the life of the session.

[Official Docs](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/)

Comment: this is precisely the main problem. I cannot use explicit expectations, because if the element is not found, I get a TimeOutException.

Comment: @Nikita: Then what is the issue with ImplicitWait ?

Comment: @круизпандей: Page load times vary, so the situation is difficult when the load timeout is too high.

Answer (score 0):

You need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the [visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65677878/webdriver-with-java-not-able-to-get-all-the-text-using-webdriver/65686528#65686528) and you can use the following solution:

```
if(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("MY_CSS_SELECTOR"))).size() != 0) {
    //...
}
```

---

### Update

To get rid of the *TimeoutException* instead of a `if-else{}` block, you may like to wrap the line of code within a `try-catch{}` block as follows:

```
try {
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("MY_CSS_SELECTOR"))).size() != 0)
    //...
}
catch(Exception e) {
  //  Block of code to handle errors
}
```

PS: Incase you implement [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) you have to remove [implicitlyWait()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50518467/how-to-properly-configure-implicit-explicit-waits-and-pageloadtimeout-through/50524225#50524225) completely because as per the [documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/#implicit-wait):

> Warning: Do not mix implicit and explicit waits. Doing so can cause unpredictable wait times. For example, setting an implicit wait of 10 seconds and an explicit wait of 15 seconds could cause a timeout to occur after 20 seconds.

Comment: but MY_CSS_SELECTOR may not be present on the page