# Unable to get the count of elements inside the div

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

HTML:

```
<div class="ui-lib-sidebar-grid__content"><div class="ui-lib-margin-b_md ui-lib-margin-t_md totalResultsText"><p class="totalResultsText">Showing 1-10 of 316 results</p></div><div class="" style=""><div class="ui-lib-category-list ui-lib-category-list-dummy"><div class="ui-lib-category-list-item"><div class="ui-lib-category-list-item__content"><div class="ui-lib-category-list-item__content-header"><div class="ui-lib-category-list-item-type"><svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid slice" data-key="" class="ui-lib-category-list-item-type__icon ui-lib-category-list-item-type__icon_service ui-lib-icon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><title></title><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="12" fill-rule="evenodd"></circle></svg><span class="ui-lib-category-list-item-type__label">Service</span></div></div><a class="ui-lib-link ui-lib-link_default" target="_self" aria-label="Request for Collection and Transfer of Green Waste from Residential Areas" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.tamm.abudhabi/en/aspects-of-life/environmentagriculture/Waste-Management/WasteCollectionandTransportation/RequestforCollectionandTransferofGreenWastefromResidentialAreas"><h4 class="ui-lib-link__heading ui-lib-bold">Request for Collection and Transfer of Green Waste from Residential Areas</h4></a><div class="ui-lib-category-list-item__description">Through this service, you can request the collection and transfer of green wastes from residential areas.</div><div class="ui-lib-category-list-item__tags"><div tabindex="0" role="button" class="ui-lib-tag ui-lib-tag_size-default ui-lib-tag_grey ui-lib-tag_hoverable ui-lib-tag_clickable"><span class="ui-lib-tag__text">Abu Dhabi Waste Management Center</span></div><div tabindex="0" role="button" class="ui-lib-tag ui-lib-tag_size-default ui-lib-tag_blue ui-lib-tag_hoverable ui-lib-tag_clickable"><span class="ui-lib-tag__text">Expat</span></div><div tabindex="0" role="button" class="ui-lib-tag ui-lib-tag_size-default ui-lib-tag_blue ui-lib-tag_hoverable ui-lib-tag_clickable"><span class="ui-lib-tag__text">Visitor</span></div><div tabindex="0" role="button" class="ui-lib-tag ui-lib-tag_size-default ui-lib-tag_blue ui-lib-tag_hoverable ui-lib-tag_clickable"><span class="ui-lib-tag__text">Emirati</span></div></div></div></div><div class="ui-lib-category-list-item"><div class="ui-lib-category-list-item__content"><div class="ui-lib-category-list-item__content-header"><div class="ui-lib-category-list-item-type"><svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid slice" data-key="" class="ui-lib-category-list-item-type__icon ui-lib-category-list-item-type__icon_service ui-lib-icon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><title></title><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="12" fill-rule="evenodd"></circle></svg><span class="ui-lib-category-list-item-type__label">Service</span></div></div><a class="ui-lib-link ui-lib-link_default" target="_self" aria-label="Request for Collection and Transfer of Large-Scale Wastes from Residential Areas" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.tamm.abudhabi/en/aspects-of-life/environmentagriculture/Waste-Management/WasteCollectionandTransportation/RequestforCollectionandTransferofLargeScaleWastesfromResidentialAreas"><h4 class="ui-lib-link__heading ui-lib-bold">Request for Collection and Transfer of Large-Scale Wastes from Residential Areas</h4></a><div class="ui-lib-category-list-item__description">Through this service, you can request the collection and transfer of wastes in large amounts from residential areas.</div><div class="ui-lib-category-list-item__tags"><div tabindex="0" role="button" class="ui-lib-tag ui-lib-tag_size-default ui-lib-tag_grey ui-lib-tag_hoverable ui-lib-tag_clickable"><span class="ui-lib-tag__text">Abu Dhabi Waste Management Center</span></div><div tabindex="0" role="button" class="ui-lib-tag ui-lib-tag_size-default ui-lib-tag_blue ui-lib-tag_hoverable ui-lib-tag_clickable"><span class="ui-lib-tag__text">Expat</span></div><div tabindex="0" role="button" class="ui-lib-tag ui-lib-tag_size-default ui-lib-tag_blue ui-lib-tag_hoverable ui-lib-tag_clickable"><span class="ui-lib-tag__text">Visitor</span></div><div tabindex="0" role="button" class="ui-lib-tag ui-lib-tag_size-default ui-lib-tag_blue ui-lib-tag_hoverable ui-lib-tag_clickable"><span class="ui-lib-tag__text">Emirati</span></div></div></div></div><div class="ui-lib-category-list-item"><div class="ui-lib-category-list-item__content"><div class="ui-lib-category-list-item__content-header"><div class="ui-lib-category-list-item-type"><svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid slice" data-key="" class="ui-lib-category-list-item-type__icon ui-lib-category-list-item-type__icon_service ui-lib-icon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><title></title><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="12" fill-rule="evenodd"></circle></svg><span class="ui-lib-category-list-item-type__label">Service</span></div></div><a class="ui-lib-link ui-lib-link_default" target="_self" aria-label="Request for Licencing a Private Notary Office" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.tamm.abudhabi/en/aspects-of-life/lawregulations/notarypublic/NotaryPublicLicensing/RequestforLicencingaPrivateNotaryOffice"><h4 class="ui-lib-link__heading ui-lib-bold">Request for Licencing a Private Notary Office</h4></a><div class="ui-lib-category-list-item__description">Apply for licencing a private notary office</div><div class="ui-lib-category-list-item__tags"><div tabindex="0" role="button" class="ui-lib-tag ui-lib-tag_size-default ui-lib-tag_grey ui-lib-tag_hoverable ui-lib-tag_clickable"><span class="ui-lib-tag__text">Abu Dhabi Judicial Department</span></div><div tabindex="0" role="button" class="ui-lib-tag ui-lib-tag_size-default ui-lib-tag_blue ui-lib-tag_hoverable ui-lib-tag_clickable"><span class="ui-lib-tag__text">Business</span></div></div></div></div><div class="ui-lib-category-list-item"><div class="ui-lib-category-list-item__content"><div class="ui-lib-category-list-item__content-header"><div class="ui-lib-category-list-item-type"><svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid slice" data-key="" class="ui-lib-category-list-item-type__icon ui-lib-category-list-item-type__icon_service ui-lib-icon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><title></title><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="12" fill-rule="evenodd"></circle></svg><span class="ui-lib-category-list-item-type__label">Service</span></div></div><a class="ui-lib-link ui-lib-link_default" target="_self" aria-label="Request for Transferring the Licence of a Private Notary from One Office to Another" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.tamm.abudhabi/en/aspects-of-life/lawregulations/notarypublic/NotaryPublicLicensing/requestfortransferringthelicenceofaprivatenotaryfromoneofficetoanother"><h4 class="ui-lib-link__heading ui-lib-bold">Request for Transferring the Licence of a Private Notary from One Office to Another</h4></a><div class="ui-lib-category-list-item__description">Apply for transferring the licence of a private notary from one office to another</div><div class="ui-lib-category-list-item__tags"><div tabindex="0" role="button" class="ui-lib-tag ui-lib-tag_size-default ui-lib-tag_grey ui-lib-tag_hoverable ui-lib-tag_clickable"><span class="ui-lib-tag__text">Abu Dhabi Judicial Department</span></div><div tabindex="0" role="button" class="ui-lib-tag ui-lib-tag_size-default ui-lib-tag_blue ui-lib-tag_hoverable ui-lib-tag_clickable"><span class="ui-lib-tag__text">Business</span></div><div tabindex="0" role="button" class="ui-lib-tag ui-lib-tag_size-default ui-lib-tag_blue ui-lib-tag_hoverable ui-lib-tag_clickable"><span class="ui-lib-tag__text">Emirati</span></div></div></div></div><div class="ui-lib-category-list-item"><div class="ui-lib-category-list-item__content"><div class="ui-lib-category-list-item__content-header"><div class="ui-lib-category-list-item-type"><svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid slice" data-key="" class="ui-lib-category-list-item-type__icon ui-lib-category-list-item-type__icon_service ui-lib-icon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><title></title><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="12" fill-rule="evenodd"></circle></svg><span class="ui-lib-category-list-item-type__label">Service</span></div></div><a class="ui-lib-link ui-lib-link_default" target="_self" aria-label="Request for Cancelling the Registration of a Private Notary Office" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.tamm.abudhabi/en/aspects-of-life/lawregulations/notarypublic/NotaryPublicLicensing/requestforcancellingtheregistrationofaprivatenotaryoffice"><h4 class="ui-lib-link__heading ui-lib-bold">Request for Cancelling the Registration of a Private Notary Office</h4></a><div class="ui-lib-category-list-item__description">Apply for cancelling the registration of a private notary office</div><div class="ui-lib-category-list-item__tags"><div tabindex="0" role="button" class="ui-lib-tag ui-lib-tag_size-default ui-lib-tag_grey ui-lib-tag_hoverable ui-lib-tag_clickable"><span class="ui-lib-tag__text">Abu Dhabi Judicial Department</span></div><div tabindex="0" role="button" class="ui-lib-tag ui-lib-tag_size-default ui-lib-tag_blue ui-lib-tag_hoverable ui-lib-tag_clickable"><span class="ui-lib-tag__text">Business</span></div></div></div></div><div class="ui-lib-category-list-item"><div class="ui-lib-category-list-item__content"><div class="ui-lib-category-list-item__content-header"><div class="ui-lib-category-list-item-type"><svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid slice" data-key="" class="ui-lib-category-list-item-type__icon ui-lib-category-list-item-type__icon_service ui-lib-icon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><title></title><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="12" fill-rule="evenodd"></circle></svg><span class="ui-lib-category-list-item-type__label">Service</span></div></div><a class="ui-lib-link ui-lib-link_default" target="_self" aria-label="Request to Open a New Branch for a Private Notary Office" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.tamm.abudhabi/en/aspects-of-life/lawregulations/notarypublic/NotaryPublicLicensing/requestforopeninganewbranchofaprivatenotaryoffice"><h4 class="ui-lib-link__heading ui-lib-bold">Request to Open a New Branch for a Private Notary Office</h4></a><div class="ui-lib-category-list-item__description">Apply for opening a new branch of a private notary office</div><div class="ui-lib-category-list-item__tags"><div tabindex="0" role="button" class="ui-lib-tag ui-lib-tag_size-default ui-lib-tag_grey ui-lib-tag_hoverable ui-lib-tag_clickable"><span class="ui-lib-tag__text">Abu Dhabi Judicial Department</span></div><div tabindex="0" role="button" class="ui-lib-tag ui-lib-tag_size-default ui-lib-tag_blue ui-lib-tag_hoverable ui-lib-tag_clickable"><span class="ui-lib-tag__text">Business</span></div></div></div></div><div class="ui-lib-category-list-item"><div class="ui-lib-category-list-item__content"><div class="ui-lib-category-list-item__content-header"><div class="ui-lib-category-list-item-type"><svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid slice" data-key="" class="ui-lib-category-list-item-type__icon ui-lib-category-list-item-type__icon_service ui-lib-icon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><title></title><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="12" fill-rule="evenodd"></circle></svg><span class="ui-lib-category-list-item-type__label">Service</span></div></div><a class="ui-lib-link ui-lib-link_default" target="_self" aria-label="Request for Renewal of a Private Notary Office Registration Card" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.tamm.abudhabi/en/aspects-of-life/lawregulations/notarypublic/NotaryPublicLicensing/requestforrenewalofaprivatenotaryofficeregistrationcard"><h4 class="ui-lib-link__heading ui-lib-bold">Request for Renewal of a Private Notary Office Registration Card</h4></a><div class="ui-lib-category-list-item__description">Apply for renewal of a private notary office registration card</div><div class="ui-lib-category-list-item__tags"><div tabindex="0" role="button" class="ui-lib-tag ui-lib-tag_size-default ui-lib-tag_grey ui-lib-tag_hoverable ui-lib-tag_clickable"><span class="ui-lib-tag__text">Abu Dhabi Judicial Department</span></div><div tabindex="0" role="button" class="ui-lib-tag ui-lib-tag_size-default ui-lib-tag_blue ui-lib-tag_hoverable ui-lib-tag_clickable"><span class="ui-lib-tag__text">Business</span></div></div></div></div><div class="ui-lib-category-list-item"><div class="ui-lib-category-list-item__content"><div class="ui-lib-category-list-item__content-header"><div class="ui-lib-category-list-item-type"><svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid slice" data-key="" class="ui-lib-category-list-item-type__icon ui-lib-category-list-item-type__icon_service ui-lib-icon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><title></title><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="12" fill-rule="evenodd"></circle></svg><span class="ui-lib-category-list-item-type__label">Service</span></div></div><a class="ui-lib-link ui-lib-link_default" target="_self" aria-label="Request Nuisance Pest Control" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.tamm.abudhabi/en/aspects-of-life/environmentagriculture/Waste-Management/PublicHealthPestControl/RequestNuisancePestControl"><h4 class="ui-lib-link__heading ui-lib-bold">Request Nuisance Pest Control</h4></a><div class="ui-lib-category-list-item__description">Through this service, you can request nuisance pest control for ants, termites, lizards, German cockroaches, ticks, fleas and bed bugs.</div><div class="ui-lib-category-list-item__tags"><div tabindex="0" role="button" class="ui-lib-tag ui-lib-tag_size-default ui-lib-tag_grey ui-lib-tag_hoverable ui-lib-tag_clickable"><span class="ui-lib-tag__text">Abu Dhabi Waste Management Center</span></div><div tabindex="0" role="button" class="ui-lib-tag ui-lib-tag_size-default ui-lib-tag_blue ui-lib-tag_hoverable ui-lib-tag_clickable"><span class="ui-lib-tag__text">Emirati</span></div></div></div></div><div class="ui-lib-category-list-item"><div class="ui-lib-category-list-item__content"><div class="ui-lib-category-list-item__content-header"><div class="ui-lib-category-list-item-type"><svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid slice" data-key="" class="ui-lib-category-list-item-type__icon ui-lib-category-list-item-type__icon_service ui-lib-icon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><title></title><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="12" fill-rule="evenodd"></circle></svg><span class="ui-lib-category-list-item-type__label">Service</span></div></div><a class="ui-lib-link ui-lib-link_default" target="_self" aria-label="Request Stray Animal Impounding" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.tamm.abudhabi/en/aspects-of-life/environmentagriculture/Waste-Management/PublicHealthPestControl/RequestStrayAnimalImpounding"><h4 class="ui-lib-link__heading ui-lib-bold">Request Stray Animal Impounding</h4></a><div class="ui-lib-category-list-item__description">Through this service, you can request and schedule impounding stray animals, such as camels, cows, cats, dogs, etc.</div><div class="ui-lib-category-list-item__tags"><div tabindex="0" role="button" class="ui-lib-tag ui-lib-tag_size-default ui-lib-tag_grey ui-lib-tag_hoverable ui-lib-tag_clickable"><span class="ui-lib-tag__text">Abu Dhabi Waste Management Center</span></div><div tabindex="0" role="button" class="ui-lib-tag ui-lib-tag_size-default ui-lib-tag_blue ui-lib-tag_hoverable ui-lib-tag_clickable"><span class="ui-lib-tag__text">Expat</span></div><div tabindex="0" role="button" class="ui-lib-tag ui-lib-tag_size-default ui-lib-tag_blue ui-lib-tag_hoverable ui-lib-tag_clickable"><span class="ui-lib-tag__text">Visitor</span></div><div tabindex="0" role="button" class="ui-lib-tag ui-lib-tag_size-default ui-lib-tag_blue ui-lib-tag_hoverable ui-lib-tag_clickable"><span class="ui-lib-tag__text">Emirati</span></div></div></div></div><div class="ui-lib-category-list-item"><div class="ui-lib-category-list-item__content"><div class="ui-lib-category-list-item__content-header"><div class="ui-lib-category-list-item-type"><svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid slice" data-key="" class="ui-lib-category-list-item-type__icon ui-lib-category-list-item-type__icon_service ui-lib-icon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><title></title><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="12" fill-rule="evenodd"></circle></svg><span class="ui-lib-category-list-item-type__label">Service</span></div></div><a class="ui-lib-link ui-lib-link_default" target="_self" aria-label="Request Vector Pest Control Service" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.tamm.abudhabi/en/aspects-of-life/environmentagriculture/Waste-Management/PublicHealthPestControl/RequestVectorPestControlService"><h4 class="ui-lib-link__heading ui-lib-bold">Request Vector Pest Control Service</h4></a><div class="ui-lib-category-list-item__description">Through this service, you can request vector pest control of mosquitos, flies, rodents and American cockroaches.</div><div class="ui-lib-category-list-item__tags"><div tabindex="0" role="button" class="ui-lib-tag ui-lib-tag_size-default ui-lib-tag_grey ui-lib-tag_hoverable ui-lib-tag_clickable"><span class="ui-lib-tag__text">Abu Dhabi Waste Management Center</span></div><div tabindex="0" role="button" class="ui-lib-tag ui-lib-tag_size-default ui-lib-tag_blue ui-lib-tag_hoverable ui-lib-tag_clickable"><span class="ui-lib-tag__text">Expat</span></div><div tabindex="0" role="button" class="ui-lib-tag ui-lib-tag_size-default ui-lib-tag_blue ui-lib-tag_hoverable ui-lib-tag_clickable"><span class="ui-lib-tag__text">Visitor</span></div><div tabindex="0" role="button" class="ui-lib-tag ui-lib-tag_size-default ui-lib-tag_blue ui-lib-tag_hoverable ui-lib-tag_clickable"><span class="ui-lib-tag__text">Emirati</span></div></div></div></div></div></div><div class="ui-lib-margin-t_ ui-lib-margin-b_xl search-pagination" style=""><div class="ui-lib-pagination ui-lib-pagination_align-center"><div class="ui-lib-pagination__item ui-lib-pagination__item_page ui-lib-pagination__item_current" aria-label="" role="button" tabindex="0">1</div><div class="ui-lib-pagination__item ui-lib-pagination__item_page" aria-label="" role="button" tabindex="0">2</div><div class="ui-lib-pagination__item ui-lib-pagination__item_page" aria-label="" role="button" tabindex="0">3</div><div class="ui-lib-pagination__item ui-lib-pagination__item_page" aria-label="" role="button" tabindex="0">4</div><div class="ui-lib-pagination__item ui-lib-pagination__item_page" aria-label="" role="button" tabindex="0">5</div><div class="ui-lib-pagination__item ui-lib-pagination__item_dots" aria-label="Next 3 Pages" role="button" tabindex="0"><svg tabindex="0" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" data-key="" class="ui-lib-pagination__item-icon ui-lib-icon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><title></title><circle cx="3.25" cy="12" r="3.25"></circle><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="3.25"></circle><circle cx="20.75" cy="12" r="3.25"></circle></svg></div><div class="ui-lib-pagination__item ui-lib-pagination__item_page" aria-label="" role="button" tabindex="0">32</div><div class="ui-lib-pagination__item ui-lib-pagination__item_nav" aria-label="Next" role="button" tabindex="0"><svg tabindex="0" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" data-key="" class="ui-lib-pagination__item-icon ui-lib-icon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><title></title><path d="M23.987,12a2.411,2.411,0,0,0-.814-1.8L11.994.361a1.44,1.44,0,0,0-1.9,2.162l8.637,7.6a.25.25,0,0,1-.165.437H1.452a1.44,1.44,0,0,0,0,2.88H18.563a.251.251,0,0,1,.165.438l-8.637,7.6a1.44,1.44,0,1,0,1.9,2.161L23.172,13.8A2.409,2.409,0,0,0,23.987,12Z"></path></svg></div></div></div></div>
```

I used this code to get the number of elements

```
List<WebElement> TotalSearchResults = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='ui-lib-sidebar-grid__content']//div[contains(@class,'ui-lib-category-list ui-lib-category-list-dummy')]/div"));
int TotalSearchCountSize = TotalSearchResults.size();
System.out.println("Total Number of Search results " +TotalSearchCountSize);
```

When running the code the number of elements in output is shown as 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output is shown as ***0*** as [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48080871/7429447) instance is initiating the search for the elements even before the desired WeElements have properly [rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47237075/7429447) within the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp). In such cases you have to synchronize the WebDriver with the *Browsing Context* using [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447).

---

### Solution

To print the number of elements you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the [`visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65677878/webdriver-with-java-not-able-to-get-all-the-text-using-webdriver/65686528#65686528) and you can use the following [locator strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//div[@class='ui-lib-sidebar-grid__content']//div[contains(@class,'ui-lib-category-list ui-lib-category-list-dummy')]/div"))).size());
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, it should have returned  `10`, However `findElements` never return any `fault/error`. if it `finds` the `elements` then it will return `a list of web element`, if not then it will `return 0`

So first to debug this issue, you should use

`driver.findElement` instead of `driver.findElements`, now most likely `driver.findElement` will return a single or first matching node in the HTML, if nothing is found then it will result in appropriate error.

In case if it returns a nosuchElement found exception then further you can debug using the below point:

`NoSuchElementException`

**Steps to check:**

1. Check if it's in any `iframe/frame/frameset`.

   **Solution:** switch to iframe/frame/frameset first and then interact with this web element.
2. Check if it's in any `shadow-root`.

   **Solution:** Use `JavaScriptExecutor('return document.querySelector` to have returned a web element and then operates accordingly.
3. Make sure that the element is rendered properly before interacting with it. Put some `hardcoded delay` or `Explicit wait` and try again.

   **Solution:** `Thread.sleep(5000)` or

   `wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(30));`
   `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//div[@class='ui-lib-sidebar-grid__content']//div[contains(@class,'ui-lib-category-list ui-lib-category-list-dummy')]/div"))).size();`
4. If you have redirected to a `new tab/ or new windows` and you have not **switched** to that particular `new tab/new window`, otherwise you will likely get `NoSuchElement` exception.

   **Solution:** switch to the relevant window/tab first.
5. If you have switched to an iframe and the new desired element is not in the same iframe context then first `switch to default content` and then interact with it.

   **Solution:** switch to default content and then switch to the respective iframe.