# Selenium: How to get all the h3 text with getText()

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

In the webpage https://cloudwise.nl/dit-is-cloudwise/alle-cloudwisers/directie/ I'm trying to get all users' names using for loop.

What I have tried so far is:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'inner')]/h3"))).getText();
```

and

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'inner')]/h3"))).getAttribute("innerHTML");
```

But all of them gets text `Directie` instead of users' name. I think it's because of the users' name is in a header `<h3>` tag and it just ignores it. How can I get the users' name within a header tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close enough. [*visibilityOfElementLocated()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49749804/7429447) will always return you the first matching element, where as you need all the matching elements.

---

### Solution

To print the *list* of **users** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the [`visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65677878/webdriver-with-java-not-able-to-get-all-the-text-using-webdriver/65686528#65686528) and you can use *Java8* [`stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) and [`map()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("div.inner h3"))).stream().map(element->element.getText()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'inner')]//h3"))).stream().map(element->element.getAttribute("innerHTML")).collect(Collectors.toList()));
  ```

Comment: I did not try that one but instead, I put 
```try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }```
before I check elements on the page. It solved the problem.

Comment: Glad to be able to help you.