# Printing All values from specific Colum "Salary"

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to print a Webtable-specific column that is Salary and am notable to figure out how to do that please help.

```
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Table {
public static void main(String[] args) {
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

driver.get("https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/test.html"); 
WebElement table =driver.findElement((By.xpath("//*[@id=\"example\"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[6]")));
Thread.sleep(10000);
for (WebElement td: table){
    System.out.println(td.getText());
}  

    driver.quit();  
} 

  }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to print the entire salary column of the table.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is the problem here.

This block of code works for me on raw Selenium

```js
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/test.html");

 driver.findElements(new By.ByCssSelector("[id=example] tr[class]")).forEach(row ->
    {
        String result = row.findElements(new By.ByTagName("td")).get(5).getText();
        System.out.println(result);
    });
```

where expectedRow - is the index of row with Salary and 5 - index of Salary column.

For sure this can be wrapped in separate method and there can be automatic column index search by getting index of th which contains aria-label "Salary", but you can do it by our own if you need it :)

Comment: I am trying to print the entire salary column not just a specific value of the column. Write something that can solve my problem.

Comment: You can use updated code snippet I provided above.

Answer (score 0):

The *Salary* is within the 6<sup>th</sup> descendant i.e. the last `<td>` of it's parent `<tr>`

---

### Solution

To print the text from the *Salary* column you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the [`visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65677878/webdriver-with-java-not-able-to-get-all-the-text-using-webdriver/65686528#65686528) and you can use *Java8* [`stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) and [`map()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/test.html");
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(5)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("table#example tbody tr td:nth-child(6)"))).stream().map(element -> element.getText()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/test.html");
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(5)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//table[@id='example']//tbody//tr//td[last()]"))).stream().map(element -> element.getText()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
  ```
- Console output:

  ```
  [$162,700, $1,200,000, $86,000, $132,000, $206,850, $372,000, $163,500, $106,450, $145,600, $433,060]
  ```